# What perl web framework to use for the old CGI based perl code?

Tags: perl

Yes, while i'm working on node.js, i still love perl, :)

The old web product is based on old perl CGI, i'm looking to the simplest way to fix XSS/Sql injection/etc. web security holes, within a week including testing, :(

So for
Catalyst
Dancer
Mason
Maypole 
Mojolicious

which one should i use in the ARM platform ?
Thank you !

Comment: A framework is neither necessary nor sufficient to solve your security problems.

Comment: angular.js does take care of some the security issue by itself, even though not all.

Comment: No, that's really not true at all. angular.js is a front-end framework; it isn't a server-side component, and there's absolutely no way you'd be able to retrofit it onto an existing web application in a way that'd have any effect on your security. (For instance, it'd do absolutely nothing about SQL injection!)

Comment: Like any other technology, AngularJS is not impervious to attack. Angular does, however, provide built-in protection from basic security holes, including cross-site scripting and HTML injection attacks. AngularJS does round-trip escaping on all strings for you and even offers XSRF protection for server-side communication.

AngularJS was designed to be compatible with other security measures like Content Security Policy (CSP), HTTPS (SSL/TLS) and server-side authentication and authorization that greatly reduce the possible attack vectors and we highly recommend their use.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq   search for "security"

Comment: Angualr is front end stuff, but go back to my point, i'm asking if any perl backend framework has already taking care of some security stuff like Angular does. The other part of my question is, if i want to re-use my old perl cgi code, which perl framework should i use now ?

Comment: I've worked with Catalyst, CGI::Application, Dancer, Mason and Mojolicious.  My current favourite is Mojolicious. It's well documented, actively maintained and is very easy to get up and running with.

Comment: Thanks you very much oalders !

Comment: I suggest you do what Borodin said, and come back with specific questions once you have made a decision. We can help with individual issues here, but not with suggesting ways to do this. If you are having a lot of trouble with that and it's critical, maybe actually hiring a professional team like Shadowcat is a good idea.

Comment: Well simbabque, i think my original question is very clear, if this site doesn't allow ppl to discuss about different software packages etc, i don't know what's the propose then. Seems there's a "political correctness" issue in this site now, makes me sick.        Thank you and all those made constructive help !

Comment: btw i stop here, pretty disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

You have fallen foul of the *primarily opinion-based* off-topic categorisation, and your question will probably be closed very soon. However I think it's worth offering a few guidelines here

First of all you should absorb what is written in [`CGI::Alternatives`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) as it is a reasonable summary of the subject

Next you should separate the HTML generation functionality of your existing CGI code from the interface itself, and consider replacements for each of them separately. If you were to use [`HTML::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tiny) together with [`CGI::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Simple) then your code would have to change very little and you would have achieved better partitioning of functionality

Ideally you will move on to one of the many templating systems such as [`Template Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template), together with one of the frameworks, which is the topic of your question. In the end you will need to do a lot of research and many trials to discover how well each framework fits your requirement, in terms of both the feature list and the convenience and clarity of the API

All I can do here is say that I am very fond of the [*Mojolicious suite*](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo) and suggest that it may be a good starting point. The API focuses on command chaining in a way similar to Ruby, and there is a [`Mojolicious::Plugin::CGI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::CGI) accessory which will allow you to execute CGI scripts unchanged during your migration

Note however that all of the frameworks that you mention, as well as several others, will have their proponents. That is why you must make the selection yourself, as such recommendations will be influenced primarily by familiarity, and without your own knowledge of the requirements of your project

Unfortunately I cannot speak to the security issues of the various options, but I hope that has helped a little

Comment: Borodin, 1st of all thanks very much for your constructive reply, it's very useful. I feel being attacked by some people here, i'm asking a question in an area that i don't know much. I saw my points get subtracted, so since i don't know about this area then i get punished ? Admin can take all my points back, i really don't need it.

Comment: There can be some intolerance from Stack Overflow's regulars, and I have been as guilty of it as anyone else. But the downvotes are not about your inexperience with the technology, but because your question is very clearly off-topic for the site. It's worth reading the Help Centre item on [*What topics can I ask about here?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Borodin, i don't know, so if  i don't know which framework to use, any other sites you can recommend ? or maybe i should just go to perl sites directly.

Comment: @user3552178: You should start with the `CGI::Alternatives` document that I have linked, and then peruse CPAN and try googling for something like *migrating from CGI.pm*. There are many people in the same boat as you are and a lot of them have written about their experiences

Comment: thank you so much Borodin, let me start reading, i stop here and you have a good weekend !

Comment: @user3552178 in addition, you are speaking about XSS and SQL injection. For the latter, make sure you at least skim https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI and maybe check http://bit.ly/1Q4TQIe. Make sure your code is using placeholders (that's the `?`) everywhere. That will give a good start. Migrating a CGI application to a framework in a few weeks time is probably only possible if we are talking about maybe 1k to 5k lines of code. Anything more will not be possible with one developer while keeping standards. Good luck.